# Google drive IO exception during fetching Files

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I want to fetch files and folder from Google Drive, i get valid Service and credential after authorization, But when i try to fetch files then it display Io Exception.

> Error: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException

My code is below where i get this IO Exception

```
 myFullDataList = new ArrayList<File>();
                Files f1 = mService.files();
                Files.List request = null;

                do 
                {
                    try 
                    { 
                        request = f1.list();
                        request.setQ("trashed=false");
                        com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList fileList = request.execute();
                        myFullDataList.addAll(fileList.getItems());
                        request.setPageToken(fileList.getNextPageToken());

                    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) 
                    {
                        startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                    } 
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                          *//Here i am getting the exception*
                        System.out.println("IOEXCEPTION"+e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        if (request != null)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Request not Null");
                            request.setPageToken(null);
                        }
                    }
                } while (request.getPageToken() !=null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
                mResultList=new ArrayList<File>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i got my solution. Actually my  SHA1 fingerprint value were not matching with my project SHA1 value which i have putted in Google developer console. So i reset the SHA1 value and the problem vanished out.